# how to build a query for "People You May Know"

Tags: php, mysql

i need to show "people you may know" based on the current friends of a user and the friend suggestion should consider blocked users,if user A blocked user B,A should not see user B or vice versa  in their friends Suggestions 
here is my table structure

mnc_users

```
id  |   username    |   email       |   fullname
---------------------------------------------------
1   |   userA       |   usera@in.in |   User Alpha
2   |   userB       |   userb@in.in |   User Bravo
3   |   userC       |   userc@im.in |   user c
4   |   userd       |   userd@am.in |   user del
```

mnc_friends

```
uid |   fid |   time
-------------------------
1   |   3   |   1363859398  
3   |   1   |   1363859398  
4   |   1   |   1368854898  
1   |   4   |   1368854898  
3   |   2   |   1363846116  
2   |   3   |   1363846116  
2   |   4   |   1363846116  
4   |   3   |   1363846116
```

mnc_blocked

```
id  |   uid |   bid
--------------------
1   |   1   |   2
```

mnc_frnd_rqsts

```
uid |   fid
-----------
5   |    1
```

how can i display users suggestions in this case using php and mysql?

Comment: which are the user suggestion in your tables?

Comment: i don't have a suggestion table i want to show in a page dynamically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if u edit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716390/how-to-build-a-query-for-people-you-may-know/20716500?noredirect=1#20716500) to add couple of things you will get it working

```
$user_id = 1;

    $sql = "    SELECT * FROM mnc_users WHERE id NOT IN(
                                             SELECT fid FROM mnc_friends WHERE uid='$user_id' AND fid!='$user_id'
                                            )
                                      AND id NOT IN(
                                            SELECT bid FROM mnc_blocked WHERE uid='$user_id'
                                           )
AND id NOT IN(
                           SELECT fid FROM mnc_frnd_rqsts WHERE uid='$user_id'
                                           )
       ";
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

suppose that we are trying to get peoples for userA:id=1

```
$user_id = 1;
```

and sql will be

```
$sql = "    SELECT * FROM mnc_users WHERE id IN(
                                         SELECT fid FROM mnc_friends WHERE uid='$user_id' AND fid!='$user_id'
                                        )
                                  AND id NOT IN(
                                        SELECT bid FROM mnc_blocked WHERE uid='$user_id'
                                       )
   ";
```

Comment: this one don't work it shows people whoz already in my friends list

Comment: yes now you can run again run this query for your friends one by one by php. you will find the friends of friends

Comment: i mean if i run this query i get my current friends list

Comment: yes get them and run above query again to each record replacing $user_id to the your friend's id.